# How to change title via button or anchor

Tags: html, css

I have a one page site with buttons on the top that direct you to different anchors, is there any way I can get the title to change every time I click the the button?

Answer (score 0):

lucky you there is a direct property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

you just do `document.title = value`